# How to all keyvalult Secret with loop

Tags: bash, azure, command-line, azure-keyvault

I have below code:

```
VaultName="ketv1"
declare -a a1=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $VaultName --query "[?attributes.expires<='2022-08-30']" -o table)

for i in "${a1[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

This code give output last keyvault secret instead of all.

```
KV-SECRET-3
```

I need output as all should be print looks like:

```
KV-SECRET-1
KV-SECRET-2
KV-SECRET-3
```

Comment: try `az keyvault secret list --vault-name $keyVaultName --query "join('\n',[].name)" --output tsv`

Comment: Check this script it can also help you : https://gist.github.com/shtratos/6c03ba89b302ff9ca6084d9ade627b79

Answer (score 1):

**I modified the script and tested in my environment with the below script and working fine for me.**

```
#!/bin/bash
VaultName="TestKey32"
declare -a a1=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $VaultName --query "join('\n',[].name)" --output tsv)
for i in "${a1[@]}"
do
  echo $i 
done
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul for giving your valuable time for my question but issue is that the result , I got the result look like "expited\nKV-Future\nKV-SECRET-1\nKV-SECRET-2\nKV-SECRET-3\nnewestkey"  and I need this value store in array which like if $a1[0],$a1[1] and needs to get value of key vault secret name in array,

Comment: I'm Windows person, If I need this powershell then It will easy for me just like piece of cake but in bash I'm learning. So, it's too difficult for me.